# Is a Mac Mini G4 capable of 1080p MP4/H.264 playback?

Tags: mac-mini, h.264

Looking for a HTPC, and I noticed the G4 Mac Minis are relatively cheap to get. I just wonder, do they support 1080p playback for MP4/H.264 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CanuckSkier said, it won't be reliable, even if it does Full HD. I have a Early 2009 lowest spec Mac Mini and it skipped enough frames to make a Full HD video unplayable when the bit rate was high enough, so i'm guessing a G4 Mac Mini would be far worse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any first-hand experience, but I'd guess not. At best you could probably get it playing but with lots of dropped frames. The graphics card is too old to have built in h.264 decoding, and I think even G5s couldn't do 1080p reliably.